# How can we prove $e^{x+y}=e^{x}e^{y}$ by the power series form of exponential function?

Tags: power-series, exponential-function

How can we prove $e^{x+y}=e^{x}e^{y}$ by the power series $$e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k}}{k!}\,\,\,?$$

Is there any simple method?

Comment: [This](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwiauMSKw_DGAhULI5QKHXFaDw0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCauchy_product&ei=FHywVZreI4vG0ATxtL1o&usg=AFQjCNHf9uGO8zXDxQvRHD1CoM6XDWf34A&bvm=bv.98476267,d.dGo) may helps you.

Comment: its easier to use $e^x=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\dfrac{x}{n})^\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Thanks for the comments from apnorton, get it.